# Multiple setup types in same module

Tags: catalog, sales, setup-script, setup

I have a module which adds some catalog attributes and some sales attributes.

Usually i would extend the correct setup type for which i want to add attributes for but obviously cannot do this here since they are both different.

My setup type is defined as `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`

This works fine for catalog attributes.

But i need to add to the sales table also.  How can this be achieved in the same module?

Specifically i am using addAttribute to ad product attribute and i also want to add a field to order_item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sales setup uses Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup. Could you not just create an object of this type and then proceed as normal.

```
$installer = Mage::getModel('sales/resource_setup', 'sales_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute(
    'order_item',
    'attribute_code',
    array(
            'label' => 'Attribute label',
            'type'  => 'type'
            )
    );
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: That doesnt work unforunately it throws an exception

Comment: shame, then i would just the suggested $setup = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('sales_setup');

Comment: I changed the code to add a parameter to `getModel` method. See if it works now.

Comment: Actually there is a problem.  The values do not persist when using $orderItem->setData().  Why would that be?

Comment: In the past I have rewritten the order item model and created getters and setters for my new attributes. Not sure if it is technically needed but that is the only non-standard thing I can see from my old code base.

Comment: I am debugging this and in the save method hasDataChanges is always false.  Even though i am using setData

Comment: did you try it with the rewrite? also are you saving this directly on the order or converting it from the quote?

Comment: No, that doesnt make sense here.  The problem is that setData('my_attribute', 'my value')->save() is not persisting the data to the database.

Comment: i think something 'eav' ish isnt tied up correcty somewhere but i dont know what or where to look

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8858/discussion-between-david-manners-and-marty-wallace)